My job halal or haram?
I work in a company as a sales manager if that company give offers to other religion festival for their product,is my job halal.if I sell that products is that shirk?

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/5166/i-work-for-a-non-muslim-printing-company-for-the-past-three-years-i-am-a-dtp-operatorgraphic-designer-i-want-to-know-if-my-rizq-is-halal-be-earning-my-salary-from-this/
It says -

It will be makrooh tahrīmī (close to harām) for you to work for this company due to directly assisting towards sin.


(Fatāwa Shāmi, Vol. 4, Pg. 268) [1]


Help one another in righteousness and piety, but help not one another in sin and animosity
> (Al Māidah,2)[2]


Therefore, it is highly advisable to either request the management not to assign you any such tasks which are contrary to shari’a or to seek alternative employment elsewhere.

This fatwa says [https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/263615]-

Summary of answer:

Lawful work should be in a permissible field and should not involve helping others to commit unlawful acts such as working in buying and selling, and rental of permissible things such as selling food, medicine, tools and equipment, and the like. It also includes working in teaching, medicine, engineering, electricity, carpentry, and manufacturing, and innumerable other permissible types of work. 2. Prohibited work includes working in Riba-based banks or commercial insurance companies, or carrying alcohol, or raising pigs, or writing down contracts of Riba, or equipping places for gambling, or selling things that it is thought most likely will be used for unlawful purposes, such as selling weapons to bandits, and other things that are regarded as prohibited and sinful, or helping in it directly or almost directly.


So most likely your condition will be kind of "disliked job but not sin" but not haram or maybe neutral type.
